# How to match word in regex -python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to match word in list when i used demo in https://regex101.com/ it's match with `\w+` but when I threw in my code the word not detected, So this is my code:

```
def MultiTrain(self):    
      for fitur in self.fiturs:
            if (fitur[0] == 'F7') or (fitur[0] == 'F8') or (fitur[0] == 'F9') or (fitur[0] == 'F10') or (
                    fitur[0] == 'F13') or (fitur[0] == 'F14') or (fitur[0] == 'F15') or (fitur[0] == 'F16') or (
                    fitur[0] == 'F17') or (fitur[0] == 'F23') or (fitur[0] == 'F24') or (fitur[0] == 'F25') or (
                    fitur[0] == 'F26') or (fitur[0] == 'F27') or (fitur[0] == 'F28') or (fitur[0] == 'F29') or (
                    fitur[0] == 'F30') or (fitur[0] == 'F37') or (fitur[0] == re.findall('\w+', fitur[0])) :
                print fitur
```

and this is the word i want to match with regex:

```
F37,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,2
F7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
F11,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
angkasa,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
action,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
acu,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
ampun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
```

The output of the program is:

```
    F37,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,2
    F7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
    F11,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

but my expectation is:

```
    F37,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,2
    F7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
    F11,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
    angkasa,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    action,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    acu,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
    ampun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
```

the fitur[0] with word not detected just the F37-F11 How can I fix the regex?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I already update the question @Rakesh

Comment: Try using `if fitur[0] in ...`, it makes for a far more readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try.

```
import re
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for fitur in infile.readlines():
        fitur = fitur.split(',')
        if (fitur[0] == 'F7') or (fitur[0] == 'F8') or (fitur[0] == 'F9') or (fitur[0] == 'F10') or (
                fitur[0] == 'F13') or (fitur[0] == 'F14') or (fitur[0] == 'F15') or (fitur[0] == 'F16') or (
                fitur[0] == 'F17') or (fitur[0] == 'F23') or (fitur[0] == 'F24') or (fitur[0] == 'F25') or (
                fitur[0] == 'F26') or (fitur[0] == 'F27') or (fitur[0] == 'F28') or (fitur[0] == 'F29') or (
                fitur[0] == 'F30') or (fitur[0] == 'F37') or (fitur[0] == re.findall('\w+', fitur[0])[0]):
            print fitur
```

`re.findall('\w+', fitur[0])` returns a list. Try using index to access the first element. Ex: `re.findall('\w+', fitur[0])[0]`

*Just a side note. This would be easier to maintain*

```
if (fitur[0] == ['F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'F10', 'F13', 'F14', 'F23', 'F24', 'F25', 'F26', 'F27', 'F28', 'F29', 'F30', 'F37']) or (fitur[0] == re.findall('\w+', fitur[0])[0]):
    print fitur
```

Comment: but in the end of the list i found this `\n`, `['F37', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '2\n']` What is that mean? Is that right? @Rakesh

Comment: and why if i change the regex with 'A-Za-z' I got `IndexError: list index out of range` actually i just want the word. I forgot if regex with `\w` its match with alphabet and the numeric. But how much with alphabet only @Rakesh

Comment: Did you try `[A-za-z]+` ?

Comment: oh sorry it works, I forgot this thing `)` Thank you so much @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

It is because re.findall('\w+',fitur[0]) is returning a list ['action']
try re.findall('\w+',fitur[0])[0] instead